# Upload my App on Apple's App Store through Company's account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

My scenario is that I created the App and the client gave me the access to their developer's account. I only have access to their Certificates, which I downloaded. Both Developer and Distribution Certificate.

I also have access to their itunesconnect with which I can upload the App.

My question is how will I be able to use those certificates and upload the App on AppStore. Client's App ID is different than mine, so I guess I'd have to change mines and create a new package.

Would I use client's certificates and create provisioning profiles through my developer account?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the basic steps, but I would recommend you to visit this site[Getting Started](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/), and follow it thoroughly.

1. Login into Developer Account.
2. Install the certificate on your Mac
3. Create a new AppID, it should be same as your Bundle ID
4. Now create development/distribution provision profile using the AppID you created in Step #3
5. Use these profile (code signing) to publish/distribute your app.

Again, above is a quick view for your help, you must follow the site I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Sarim, the certificate I am gonna install would be my client's certificate right? Would it be his Developer or Distribution Certificate?

Comment: Yes, if you are publishing it on app store/adhoc then it would be distribution certificate otherwise for development purpose you are going to use development certificate.

Comment: If the above helped you, please take time to mark it as your answer.

Comment: So Sarim, here is the problem. for #3. I am really new at this. I am creating a Provisioning from client's Certificate. But when I create the App ID  which is similar to Client, it gives me error `An App ID with Identifier 'com.client.app' is not available. Please enter a different string.` What should I do here.

Comment: AppID should be globally unique, which means it should be unique not only in your scope/profile but also across the board. so you need to chose a different Bundle ID here, anything but it must be unique, in your case, someone has already use com.client.app so it can not be re-used.

Comment: But, they allowed me to only upload the App with their Bundle ID. On itunesconnect, their Bundle ID is pre-filled, hence I can only upload my app if I have their Bundle ID, right? Any suggestion on this?

Comment: If your iTunes connect already have this APP ID, then you dont need to create one, just use the existing one while creating provision profiles. Hope this helps